# Check DateTime is greater than C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to output a sequence of dates with Inclusive of the ending date. For some reasons if the Day part of the starting date is greater than the Day part of the End Date, the end date is not included. Below is my code with sample output,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       var StartDate = DateTime.Parse("06/28/2019");
        var EndDate = DateTime.Parse("09/27/2019");

        var Daily = 1;
        for (var i = EndDate; i > StartDate; i = i.AddMonths(Daily))
        {
            // Get the first of each month
            int month = i.Month;
            int year = i.Year;
            var FirstDay = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
            // Get the difference between first day and first Friday
            int difference = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday - (int)FirstDay.DayOfWeek;
            int adddays = difference > 0 ? 21 : 28;
            int days = difference + adddays;
            var ForthTues = FirstDay.AddDays(days);
            Console.WriteLine(ForthTues);
        }
    }
```

This code above will give the output

```
6/24/2019
7/22/2019
8/26/2019
```

but if I change the dates to below,

```
var StartDate = DateTime.Parse("06/27/2019");
var EndDate = DateTime.Parse("09/28/2019");
```

I get the correct output I am looking for which is

```
6/24/2019
7/22/2019
8/26/2019
9/23/2019
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Stepping through with a debugger and looked at what's happening with the variables etc.? In other words: have you made an attempt to try to understand what's going on?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that could output something...so where does your output come from and how should we know it's correct or not?

Comment: But for a wild guess: `i <= EndDate;` will be false for an `EndDate` of `09/27/2019` and an `i` of `09/28/2019` (which is what your loop computes by adding months to the start date.)

Comment: the second case only works because the last iteration coes beyond end date when adding months

Comment: It _should_ work if your `AddMonths(Daily)` call is just adding a month.. but ... well... what IS it doing?!?!

Comment: Seems like you should truncate the day to your start and end dates before iterating.

Comment: Below is my entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your code into something non-region specific, and with a little tweaking, what you appear to want is as follows:-

```
         var StartDate = new DateTime(2019,  6, 28);
         var EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 9, 27);

         var startMonth = StartDate.AddDays(1 - StartDate.Day);
         var endMonth = EndDate.AddDays(1 - EndDate.Day);

         for (var i = startMonth; i <= endMonth; i = i.AddMonths(1))
         {
            int difference = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday - (int)i.DayOfWeek;
            int addDays = difference >= 0 ? 21 : 28;
            int days = difference + addDays;
            var fourthTuesday = i.AddDays(days);
            if (fourthTuesday <= EndDate )
               Console.WriteLine(fourthTuesday);
         }
```

Comment: I have just tested this code above and it doesn't work. I have updated my question with the complete code

Comment: The output I get from the above is:
24/06/2019 00:00:00
22/07/2019 00:00:00
26/08/2019 00:00:00
23/09/2019 00:00:00
(UK date format). What about this is wrong?

Comment: You are correct. Sorry. It gives me the correct out put. Thanks

Comment: I'm not convinced that it should show the first date is it is before the official start date, but that's your call (modify the IF statement to exclude this).